# Redirect urls with query string to seo-friendly directory like urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, seo

I know this question is asked by many users, also I gone through many questions to find the solutions as I am unable to understand the code used in htaccess file. So please kindly help me to solve this issue. I just want to convert a link like:

> www.abc.com/project.php?proj-cat=some+project+name

to url like:

> www.abc.com/project/some+project+name

OR to like:

> www.abc.com/project/some-project-name/

I googled and found a website which creates a htaccess rule for you, using this site I got this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule project/proj-cat/(.*)/ project.php?proj-cat=$1 [L]
```

but this doesn't redirect to the links above.
Please help me to find the solution for this and help me understand how it works. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+project\.php\?proj-cat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ project/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^project/([^/.]+)/?$ project.php?proj-cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

#### Reference: 1. [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)

#### 2. http://askapache.com

Comment: Thanks @anubhava it worked but now the problem the css/scripts not getting applied to that page.

Comment: ok for css/js just use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.
   You can try adding this in your page's HTML header: `<base href="/" />` so that every relative URL is resolved from that URL and not the current URL.

Comment: Thanks you so much, But can you help me understand how to interpret this, and from where i can learn this from begining?

Comment: I have added 2 reference links in the answer, that are really useful. Go through them when you get some time and if there is any specific question, feel free to ask and I will try to answer it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58479/discussion-between-sagar-guhe-and-anubhava).