# .htaccess rewrite only when there is a slash in the URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

In my root directory I have files but I want the rewrite to work only if there is a slash.

I have urls at the moment as `www.mysite.com/index.php?id=10&id1=234`. I want instead to have urls like `www.mysite.com/234` that rewrite to `passthrough.php?id=234`.

I will use php to redirect. The important point is the rewrite should only happen if there is a slash so it does not conflict with other stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect urls with query string to seo-friendly directory like urls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25061324/redirect-urls-with-query-string-to-seo-friendly-directory-like-urls)

Comment: Where is the "slash", the start of the request URI? `/index.php` and `/234` both have a slash in the same place.

Comment: Sorry I should have made it clearer. Really I want it to only redirect if it does not resolve - in the above example index.php.... would resolve.

Comment: Sorted it out now thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this out now thanks by simply looking at the rewrite template and all works fine. It can be a bit confusing when you first use such things!